# Firefox's CSS3 "nth-child" support?

Tags: firefox, css-selectors, css

According to css3.info's [selector test](http://www.css3.info/selectors-test/), Firefox 3.0 supports some permutations of the nth-child selector. However, the code shown [here](http://www.css3.info/selectors-test/test-nthchild.html) (#30) doesn't work for me.

It should select the empty paragraphs, so I edited my code to the following but it doesn't show in Firefox (it works in Opera).

```
<style type="text/css">
div :nth-child(even) {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 30px;
}
</style>

<div>
    <div>Does this element match?</div>
    <div></div>
    <div>Does this element match?</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Is this a bug in the test, or have I made an error somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm... according to [this page](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) Firefox 3.0 does not support `:nth-child`.

Comment: Verified - Safari 3 your code works. FF 3 it doesn't. There's also a difference between div:nth-child(even) and div :nth-child(even)

Comment: I just tested 3.0.8 and this was the result for :nth-child()(47 out of 88 failed).
Including :nth-child(even)

Comment: However, it did pass div :nth-child(2n+0) {} which also selects evens.

Comment: After some testing on my own, I think their tests are not working.  I saw a lot of duplicate tests, with 1 pass and 1 fail.

Comment: I'm aware that Firefox doesn't officially support nth-child, which is why I was suprised that apparently some of those tests passed. I guess the test is broken in some way, since FF doesn't appear to support nth-child in any form.

Answer (score 1):

if you use jquery [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild#index) might help you (jquery don't care what browser your user is using:) )

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox 3.5, your test case now works as expected.

Comment: yeah, I was about to say... I use nth-child all the time with firefox and it works. I'm using 3.5 though.

Comment: Well this question was asked 3 months before Firefox 3.5 was released... anyway the question was more about why apparently half the nth-child tests passed and half didn't.